# performSelectorOnMainThread waitUntilDone:YES advantage over simple call

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the reason that you would ever use

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(example:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

over a simpler

```
[self example];
```

call.

It seems like they both do the same thing. All I see is that the `performSelectorOnMainThread` seems harder to debug in xcode, but otherwise makes no difference.

Comment: There's a big difference if the current thread isn't the main thread.

Comment: I see a lot of examples of people doing this on the main thread. Are they just using it needlessly then?

Comment: Calling `performSelectOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` from the main thread and passing `YES` to the `waitUntilDone:` parameter is the same as directly calling the selector. In other words, it's pointless.

Comment: I don't agree, considering atomicity. Having a thread "wait" does not prevents race conditions with other threads, including the main one. Having some code always performing on the main threads helps in such a case, even if this might not be the best pattern to use.

Comment: The actual fact of big difference is event scheduling/management are  in main run loop cycle. So Method direct calling is directly calling on main thread and perform selector method calling according to scheduling run loop cycle that's why its hard to debug line by line. Go through multithreading apple doc.

Answer (score 1):

If the current thread is the main thread, you're right, it will do the same thing as calling the selector directly.

But obviously, there's no reason to call `performSelectorOnMainThread:` while on the main thread (except if you're not sure the current thread is the main one).

Calling this method will ensure the selector will be executed on the main thread, while being on another one, which can be very important for various reasons.
An example is everything related to the UI, as these kind of stuff should usually never be done on a secondary thread.

Imagine the following:

```
dispatch_async
(
    dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0 )
    ^( void )
    {
        /* Do heavy work, not blocking the main thread */

        [ myView setBackgroundColor: [ UIColor redColor ] ];
    }
);
```

The following code is generally considered as dangerous, as you're accessing a UI property from a secondary thread. UI properties should generally only be accessed from the main thread.

This is why you'll use `performSelectorOnMainThread:`:

```
dispatch_async
(
    dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0 )
    ^( void )
    {
        /* Do heavy work, not blocking the main thread */

        [ myView performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector( setBackgroundColor: ) withObject: [ UIColor redColor ] waitUntilDone: YES ];
    }
);
```

**EDIT**

You might think that since your passing `YES` for the `waitUntilDone:` argument, it should be the same as calling the selector directly.

But no. The issue is that the called selector might not be synchronised, in order to work from different threads.

Think about setting a property, as in the above example. If the property is `nonatomic`, you might have issues, even if your own thread "waits" until the selector is performed, as this does not prevent race conditions with other threads (including the main one).

**EDIT 2**

By the way, when accessing properties from different threads, declaring them as `atomic` is obviously preferred than using `performSelectorOnMainThread:` each time you need to access them.
Also consider `dispatch_sync` or `dispatch_async`, passing `dispatch_get_main_queue` as first argument, as it is usually a nicer way to rejoin the main thread.

Comment: Minor comment - using `performSelectorOnMainThread:` from the main thread makes sense (under the right needs) when `NO` is passed to `waitUntilDone:`.

Comment: @rmaddy See the edit - It might also have sense in regard to atomicity.

Comment: Clarify your edit. Assuming it applies to calling `performSelectOnMainThread` from the main thread with `YES`, it is still no different than directly calling the method.

Comment: That's actually the first sentence of my answer... Or maybe you meant something else?

Comment: Now I'm more confused then. Your first sentence states one thing (which agrees with my 2nd comment to the answer) but you imply your 1st edit means something else. Which is it?

Comment: @rmaddy Always calling a selector on the main thread, on all code paths, might act as a kind of synchronisation mechanism, even if there's of course better patterns for that, because it prevents race conditions. Waiting might help with your secondary thread, regarding the main one, but what if you have a third one accessing the same selector?

Comment: OK. That's all fine. Your comment below my second comment of the question says it disagrees with my comment. But the 1st sentence of your answer fully agrees with my 2nd comment below the answer. I didn't comment about other threads. So the confusion is why your comment disagrees with mine. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Might as well post the comments as an answer.

Calling `performSelectOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` from the main thread and passing `YES` to the `waitUntilDone:` parameter is the same as directly calling the selector. In other words, it's pointless.

Passing `NO` makes a big difference. The selector is queued up and will run later.

And of course there's a big difference if the current thread isn't the main thread.

Actually I can think of one reason to use `performSelectOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` with `YES` from the main thread - code that might be called from any thread, including the main thread.

Comment: Your last point is a good one, but it's not the only reason. You may have many threads accessing a same selector, needing to wait. Not just only two. If the selector is not properly synchronised, with a mutex for instance, always using the main thread helps in such a case.

Comment: The OP never wrote about calling `performSelectorOnMainThread:` **from the main thread**. Guess you'll have to read the question again : )

Comment: @Macmade Sorry, it's from the 1st comment posted by the OP below the question. I was going off of that.

Comment: No worries - Then, in that specific case I agree with your answer. But I don't think it was the whole point of the question.